# How to solve java issue of Mathcad Integration Node in ModeFrontier?

Tags: java, optimization, mathcad

I'm testing the modeFrontier with a simple multi-objective optimization problem
from [ESTECO A simple multi-objective optimization problem](http://www.math.unipd.it/~marcuzzi/DIDATTICA/LEZ&ESE_PIAI_Matematica/3_cones.pdf)

The ModeFrontier gives random values to the input variables `h` and `r` but it can't get values for the output variables `b`, `l` and `v`

[image: Designs Table]

Then I test the mathcad configuration. This was the output message:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.RemoteException: Exception starting the process; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.RemoteException: Initialization error; nested exception is: 
    com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object
```

[image: Mathcad test]

Preferences of Mathcad in ModeFrontier:
[image: Mathcad Preferences in modeFrontier]

Mathcad Preferences Script Security:
[image: Mathcad Preferences Script Security]

Below is the diagram of ModeFrontier:

[image: ModeFrontier diagram]

The mathcad worksheet:

[image: Mathcad worksheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason of this problem, but I could solve when I ran the ModeFrontier as Administrador.

There is very problems if the ModeFrontier didn't run as administrator.
Then I recommend run always as administrator.

For run always as administrator, you can go to the ModeFrontier's icon. Right click on it and click on ***properties***, finally click on check button "***Run as administrator***".
[image]
[image]